# How to compile Chromium lasted src tarball download from https://gsdview.appspot.com?

Tags: compilation, chromium

My internet connection is very slow and blocked to google,I have a VPN connection,but it's very unstable, I can't get full chromium lasted source code using depot_tools (http://dev.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code).

I download the lasted src tarball from https://gsdview.appspot.com/chromium-browser-official/ .
Somebody knows how to compile Chromium based on this tarball,or is there anyway else for me to get the lasted src code be abled to compile? Thanks!

Comment: Did you che the http://dev.chromium.org/developers/how-tos page?

Comment: Yes,I did.It seems that using src tarball is not offcially supported.